# On Windows 7, any good way to embed video rendering in a window programmatically?

Tags: video, windows-7, rendering

On Windows 7, process A decodes video and process B renders it in a embedded view,just like Flash plugin for Browsers. Process B is just like a window compositor which is responsible to compose some opengl textures or bitmap buffers to a final window. process B can add some toolbar on top of the embedded video view or embed video rendering.
Any efficient way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible if you can get the HWND of the video area. With it you can add buttons, toolbars, menus, etc on top of it just like you could a blank area on a vanilla window. It is possible to even draw with DirectX or OpenGL on an HWND, so you could do some serious Picture in Picture while watching the FBI warnings.